# Selected Item of row in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Hi I am using a `Listview` in my application and I created separate xml for the layout of each row of that `ListView`. Each row contains two `ImageView` and one One `TextView`. I want to get which `ImageView` is clicked on that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the tag with each imageView in getView function of the adapter....

```
imageView.setTag(Postion);
```

and get in onclick with view that you received......

Answer (score 2):

You can set `OnClickListener` in `Adapter` class itself inside `getView()` and get the Click Listener working for both the images. As, you haven't posted any code it not feasible to guess.

Comment: thanx Lalit, it works but how to get row number on which click action performed

Comment: you can use `imageview.setTag(position)` and get the position inside `onClick()` using `int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();` also check my blog [here](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        system.out.println("position"+position)
                             }});
```